# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity from csv to Azure Synapse is failing with identity columns in synapse tables

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am trying to do a simple copy data from csv in ADLS to Azure Synapse in ADF Pipeline . I have also set pre Copy script to Identity Insert ON but still the Copy activity fails with "An explicit value for the identity column in table  can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON".

I know that if identity insert is ON the Synapse will expect the column names to be listed but how do we do it in copy activity of ADF ?
Or how to copy data from csv to synapse with identity column in Azure synapse ?

Comment: Are you trying to insert data into an identity column via copy activity? If no, then skip the column in mapping

Comment: Yes I am trying to insert the identity column also. I tried Bulk Insert in the copy activity. Which worked fine. Is that the right approach ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are copying data into an identity column, ADF auto takes care w.r.t identity insert on and Off, there is no explicit need to execute anything.
So bulk insert would work.
[image]

Comment: Great it could help! Can you please upvote and mark it as answer as it benefit other community members as well